# Alpine Linux: Can I bridge the eth0 to WiFi?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, ip, alpine-linux

**The problem:** I have Alpine Linux downloaded on my phone, but it cannot be pinged by other devices on the network. It seems to have its own IP address and gateway that is different from the network. My network has the range of 192.168.1.X/24 and gateway of 192.168.1.1, while the Alpine Linux has 192.168.50.15 and gateway of 192.168.50.2. This results in the Alpine Linux not being pinged by other devices on the network.

**Proposed solution:** Is there a way I can create a network bridge between the wifi of the network and the eth0 of Alpine Linux? That way Alpine Linux gets a valid IP address and uses the router as the gateway, making it visible on the network.

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
                                                                                          
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static                                                               
      hostname alpine                                                                 
      address 192.168.50.15
      netmask 255.255.255                                                             
      gateway 192.168.50.2
```

Comment: Looks like Alpine Linux isn't really in control of the phone, but probably running as a kind of container or VM. Is your phone connected using Ethernet? If no, why would Alpine Linux present an Ethernet interface name rather than a wireless interface name? So you can't do anything useful from it . That's not even talking about the actual difficulty: bridging Ethernet+Wifi anywhere else than on the Access Point whatever the OS involved.

Comment: Just noticed that instead of fixing your previous question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756857/how-do-i-connect-alpine-linux-to-wifi you asked this instead, which is the same question with more background (and needed) information.