# Network bridge between Termux and Alpine Linux QEMU

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, ip, android

I have an Android phone with **Termux**. Using Termux I downloaded **Alpine Linux x86 QEMU**.

**The problem:** Other devices on the network cannot ping and communicate with the Alpine Linux QEMU. So that's why I want to create a network bridge from Termux to the Alpine Linux QEMU, thereby making the Alpine Linux visible and accessible for other devices on the network.

**Termux:**

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0                       unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
                                                                                       
 wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
            unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 3000  (UNSPEC)
```

**startqemu.sh:**

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -machine q35 -m 1024 -smp cpus=2 -cpu qemu64 \                                                 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,read-only,file=$PREFIX/share/qemu/edk2-x86_64-code.fd \
  -netdev user,id=n1,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22,net=192.168.50.0/24,hostfwd=tcp::9000-:9000 -device virtio-net,netdev=n1 \
  -nographic alpine.img
```

**I'm really new to all of this, so can anyone help me set this up?**

Comment: 3rd question for the same problem, see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756857/how-do-i-connect-alpine-linux-to-wifi and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756876/alpine-linux-can-i-bridge-the-eth0-to-wifi . Now we see that in addition to the impossibility due to Wifi client, the VM uses [user mode network emulation](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_(SLIRP)), possibility due to lack of control of the host (android): can't be bridged either. Why don't you improve a former question instead of asking a new one? Anyway there might be no solution.